# Object inside object with retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

i need to send @Body like next:

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "test2": {
       "test2": "test2",
       "test2": "test2",
  },
  "test3": {
       "test3": "test3",
       "test3": "test3",
  },
}
```

I am new with retrofit, I know how to create simple @Body object, but how create objects inside object - I have no idea.

will be glad any help!

Comment: I don't understand. Just put objects in your object. How do you create the Body in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Just create classes for these inner objects, and aggregate them into one object:

```
class TestWrapper {

    @Expose
    String test;

    @Expose
    Test2 test2;

    @Expose
    Test3 test3;
}

class Test2 {

    @SerializedName("something_name") // <- this will be the JSON key name
    @Expose
    String something;

    @SerializedName("something_else_name")
    @Expose
    String somethingElse;
}
```

etc.
Then pass the TestWrapper object as the request @Body.
Also, not that in your JSON you named two objects the same ("test2", "test3") - you can't do it, keys must be unique.
Annotations in this code are the GSON library annotations:
[@Expose](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) and
[@SerializedName](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Retrofit uses Gson as the default JSON converter, so that's why the solution above is perfect.

Comment: When serializing with Gson, it will use the name of the field for a key, or, if it's annotated with @SerializedName("custom_name"), the key will be whatever string is in the annotation (in this case: "custom_name")

Comment: @invariant, i need create keyName for all class Test2. how to create keyName for string etc. - I know  :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand you, but if you want to have a same key for all objects of a class, you can do it by setting the same @SerializedName to every object, but DON'T do this, for the reason specified in the answer. Keys must be unique. (If that's not what you're asking for, you've got to be more specific)